# how to make dojo charts support mirroring

Tags: dojo, mirroring, dojox.charting

iam trying to make dojo charts support mirroring (rtl drawing).in any dojo charts the x-axis and y-axis (0,0)start drawing from the left-bottom corner of the screen and the value of both increasing to right and upwards.what i want is to make these dojo charts start drawing from the right-bottom corner of the screen and the the value increasing to right and upwards.i just started learning dojo and i am not very good in javascript,but my main problem is i dont know where to find the function (in dojo lib) which responsible for drawing the charts so i can understand it and do the needed modification to reach my goal.i hope anybody help me find it (or even give me any advise helping me complete this task)....thanks

Answer (score 1):

Axes can be placed on all four sides. For example, if you want to place an vertical axis on the right side, just specify `leftBottom: false` in its parameters, when adding it to a chart.

Reversing the drawing order is a little bit more involved. First order of business is to inverse `x` coordinates of your data (the trick is to use the full data point specification: `{x, y, tooltip}`). You probably want to preserve original values on axis' ticks. In order to do so just use custom labels, either statically generated, or a function.

You can read all about it in the official documentation: [Configuring Axes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/charting.html#configuring-axis) and [Data Management](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/charting.html#data-management), which explains all details and illustrate them with code snippets.